# Add keys/values to Dictionary at declaration

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, dictionary, declaration

Very easy today, I think.  In C#, its:

```
Dictionary<String, String> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "", "" } };
```

But in vb, the following doesn't work.

```
Public dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String) (("",""))
```

I'm pretty sure there's a way to add them at declaration, but I'm not sure how.  And yes, I want to add them at declaration, not any other time.  :)  So hopefully it's possible.  Thanks everyone.

I've also tried:

```
Public dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String) ({"",""})
```

And...

```
Public dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String) {("","")}
```

And...

```
Public dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String) {{"",""}}
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

This is possible in VB.NET 10:

```
Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String) From {{ 1, "Test1" }, { 2, "Test1" }}
```

Unfortunately IIRC VS 2008 uses VB.NET 9 compiler which doesn't support this syntax.

And for those that might be interested here's what happens behind the scenes (C#):

```
Dictionary<int, string> VB$t_ref$S0 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
VB$t_ref$S0.Add(1, "Test1");
VB$t_ref$S0.Add(2, "Test1");
Dictionary<int, string> dict = VB$t_ref$S0;
```

Comment: fine! I wonder how that behaves, does it build the two dimensional array first, and then it copies to the dictionary?

Comment: Dern. So you're saying that since I'm using VS2008 I can't do it? That stinkies.

Comment: Yeap, a bit stinky :-) Time to upgrade.

Comment: Is there any way to convert a two dimensional array to a dictionary?  If so, I'll just do that.  My goal is that I have ViewModes and each mode has a separate query.  I wanted to iterate through the dictionary, add the key to a view mode combo box, and the value would be the query.  Or something of the sort.  Maybe I'll have to use a two-dimensional array.

Comment: I ended up just making it a property and adding them in there.  Don't know why I didn't think of it before.

Comment: With how it works behind the scenes, does `VB$t_ref$S0` have the same scope as `dict`? is `VB$t_ref$S0` Garbage Collected immediately? What if `dict` was a public property?

Answer (score 18):

It is much the same, use the `From` keyword:

```
    Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"", ""}}
```

However, this requires version 10 of the language, available in VS2010.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a cool translation:  You can also have a Generic Dictionary of strings and string array.

**C#**:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string[]> dics = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
{
    {"sizes", new string[]  {"small", "medium", "large"}},
    {"colors", new string[]  {"black", "red", "brown"}},
    {"shapes", new string[]  {"circle", "square"}}
};
```

**VB**:

```
Private Shared ReadOnly dics As New Dictionary(Of String, String()) From {
 {"sizes", New String() {"small", "medium", "large"}},
 {"colors", New String() {"black", "red", "brown"}},
 {"shapes", New String() {"circle", "square"}}}
```

Cool haa :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no constructor to take a KeyValuePair for a dictionary.